# using loops to traverse through the array in linux to execute query within sqlplus

Tags: arrays, shell, sqlplus

I have shell script with following code:

```
#! /bin/bash

MODEL=$1
declare -a arr=("porsche" "lamborgini" "tesla")

for i in ${arr[@]}
do
sqlplus -s un/pass <<!
set verify off
INSERT INTO tbl1 (par1, par2, par3, datetime_parm)
VALUES('$MODEL', '${arr[i]}', (select count(s) from table i), SYSTIMESTAMP);
COMMIT;
exit;
!
done
```

For some reason it is overwriting  the previous value it gets from the array and i ends up only populating the table with 'tesla'.

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
#! /bin/bash

MODEL=$1
declare -a arr=("porsche" "lamborgini" "tesla")

for i in ${arr[@]}
do
sqlplus -s un/pass <<!
set verify off
INSERT INTO tbl1 (par1, par2, par3, datetime_parm)
VALUES('$MODEL', '$i', (select count(s) from table i), SYSTIMESTAMP);
COMMIT;
exit;
!
done
```

Comment: All I had to do is pass variable $i